# Creating login page in angular 5

Tags: node.js, express, angular5

How to create a login page and check data's in a database using Rest API in angular 5.I am using Node js and Mysql as my database

Answer (score 0):

There are many moving parts to creating an authentication system, and there are simply too many ways to get it wrong: storing plain-text passwords, not salting hashes, not rate-limiting queries, not having a properly configured TLS certificate, et cetera...

As you are not very familiar with these important concepts, it is highly advisable to use a 3rd-party OAuth2 provider in order to provide user authentication.

I repeat: I highly discourage implementing your own login page/fields and authentication methods for limiting database access.

As an example, take a look at [this following option](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client) of using Google as an OAuth2 provider in your NodeJS application.